# Trying to Update my database (Laravel) with some javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, apache, server

The code is working just fine on my local machine, but when I upload it to the server it doesn't work.

This is my back end code:

```
public function changeCodePost(Request $request)
{
    $s = Setting::all()->first();
    $s->update([
        'code' => $request->scriptCode
    ]);
    alert()->success('تم الحفظ');
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

And here is the form:

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('code.post')}}">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="scriptCode" class="form-control" value="{{$code}}">
    </div>
    @error('scriptCode')
    {{$message}}
    @enderror
    <button class="btn btn-primary">حفظ</button>
</form>
```

Please help, could it be the server I'm uploading on?
I want to save a value such as:

[image]

but only when I enter a value like `<script></script>` it doesn't work.

Comment: laravel doesn't show you any error? look at the logs

Comment: nothing at all i works fine for my local machine